# Json Encode Getting Repeated Data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, smarty

I create function for listing data in Smarty. It Works fine but my problem is i am getting data twice.please help me .

My Function is as below:

```
function appListing($requestvars)
{

        try 
        {
            $rh = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM app');
            //$rh->bindParam(':userOwnerId', $_SESSION['userId'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $rh->execute();
            $appData['App'] = $rh->fetchAll();
            $this->smartyTemplate->assign('appData', $appData);
            $this->smartyTemplate->assign('request', $requestvars);
            $this->smartyTemplate->assign('homePath', APP_ROOT_DIR);
            //$this->smartyTemplate->display('project/appList.html');
        } 
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            $appData = "Error!: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    echo json_encode($appData);
}
```

Output i am getting is as below:

```
{
 "App": [
 {
  "0": "app_57ba9fc847dd55_57218508",
  "1": "旅行台南",
  "2": "https://play.google.com/",
  "3": "https://play.google.com/1471848392.png",
  "4": "1471848392",
  "5": "1471848392",
  "appId": "app_57ba9fc847dd55_57218508",
  "appName": "旅行台南",
  "appURL": "https://play.google.com/",
  "appImage": "https://play.google.com/1471848392.png",
  "createTime": "1471848392",
  "lastUpdateTime": "1471848392"
 }
```

i want output as:

```
{
 "App": [
 {
  "appId": "app_57ba9fc847dd55_57218508",
  "appName": "旅行台南",
  "appURL": "https://play.google.com/",
  "appImage": "https://play.google.com/1471848392.png",
  "createTime": "1471848392",
  "lastUpdateTime": "1471848392"
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`. The default for `fetchAll()` is `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`, which returns an array with both numeric and named indexes.

```
        $appData['App'] = $rh->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```